# MS Teams for Iphone: incorrect displaying russian characters inside the thumbnail cards

Tags: iphone, microsoft-teams

I have a chatbot for MS Teams based on the BotFramework. When I return a ThumbnailCard from my chatbot to user, a russian charachter 'м' displays incorrectly like `'&#1084;'`. This appears only on MS Teams for IPhone and not every time. Sometimes it displays correctly.

Screenshot:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f5fxD.png)

I noticed, if I wrap text into a span tag, it displays correctly more often. But in general it doesn't help.
Also I asked the Microsoft Office 365 support to help me, but they redirected me to ask my question here.

```
// controller
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post([FromBody] Activity activity)
{
    // getting a text and a subtitle
    var response = CreateAttachments(text, subtitle);
    return Request.CreateResponse<ComposeExtensionResponse>(response);
}

private ComposeExtensionResponse CreateAttachments(string text, string subtitle)
{
    var card = new ThumbnailCard { Text = text, Subtitle = subtitle };
    var response = new ComposeExtensionResponse(new ComposeExtensionResult("list", "result"));
    response.ComposeExtension.Attachments = new List<ComposeExtensionAttachment>{card.ToAttachment().ToComposeExtensionAttachment()};
    return response;
}
```

Expecting 'м' character should display correctly, not like `'&#1084;'`

Comment: could you please share a screenshot of the issue you have faced?

Comment: @Gousia-MSFT Shure, Here it is: https://i.stack.imgur.com/f5fxD.png

Comment: I have raised a bug for this. We are looking into it.

Comment: This is fixed now.